# Multiple conditions on filtered index in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

can we create filter index on multiple where conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Example:

```
create table TestTable (
  id int identity primary key,
  a varchar(50),
  b varchar(50)
)

create nonclustered index TestTableFilteredIndex 
on TestTable (b)
where id > 100 
  and a is not null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e8e5)

[More information on filtered indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx).